# Finatra - how to add url encoder

Tags: twitter-finagle, finatra

I have a finatra server, in the response string there are currency symbols.
which looks fine in the server but in the browser I get Â£5.25 instead of £5.25

any advice on how to fix this issue? recommended url encoder?

thanks,
Dana

Answer (score 0):

just needed to add encoder to the header so the browser will know which encoder to use :)

response.contentType("text/javascript; charset=utf-8")